# Remove from other SQL table after using the Match function?

Tags: sql-server

I found this code online and like its use for inserting data based on common column variables.

```
 Select * from Table1 
    Merge into table1 as T using [table] as S 
on T.[Last Name] = S.[Last Name] and T.[First Name] = S.[First Name] 
    When Matched then Update Set T.[DOB] = S.[DOB];
```

Problem is I want to get rid of the data that matched up from the source. So, once the information is has been matched and inserted into the target I want to delete the matched information from the source.

Comment: Which table do you want to delete from? The table you want to delete from would be the merge table, the table you want to check would be the using table, then you'd just have `WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE`. But realistically, if all you're doing is a delete statement and nothing else then don't bother with a merge. Just do a normal delete statement. e.g. `DELETE T1 FROM tblMyDeletingTable T1 JOIN myOtherTable T2 ON T2.X = T1.X;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the merge statement you can do a delete statement using inner join:

```
DELETE T1
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
ON T1.[Last Name]  = T2.[Last Name] AND T1.[First Name]  = T2.[Last Name];
```

> **Note:** By default SQL table names are not case-sensitive, so both Table1 and table1 will refer to the same table. So please change the table
>   name.

Comment: Ok, I will try this out. will this delete from the [table] referred as S for source or will it delete from the Target [table1] as T?

Comment: @jjtheflash, This is a normal delete query. Here you don't have to worry about source and target. This will delete from Table1. If you want to delete from table2, swap the table names accrodingly.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'T1'. and it also gives the same error for the inner

Comment: awesome it works, one last question does it matter about the capitalization of the names? can they include or not include the capital letters as long as they match?

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. By default the SQL server naming conventions are not case-sensitive. So you can't differentiate table based on just capitalization. So the better practice is to go for a different table name.

Comment: @jjtheflash, You can mark it as the correct answer and give an upvote if it worked for you so that it can be useful for the others as well.